# function doesnt print out all the even numbers?

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I have to write it this way with two functions for class but am having trouble printing all the even numbers instead of just 1.

```
def is_even(the_value):
if the_value % 2 == 0:
    return True
else:
    return False

def find_even(the_list):
even_list = []
for sublist in the_list:
    if is_even(sublist):
        even_list.append(sublist)
        return even_list


a_list = [50,23,30,41,99]
print(find_even(a_list))
```

Should print:

```
[50,30]
```

instead, I get:

```
[50]
```

Thanks

Comment: `return even_list` is incorrectly indented. It should be executed after the loop, NOT inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because `return` only returns once.

So do the below,, much shorter and faster:

```
def find_even(l):
    return [i for i in l if not i%2]
```

**Demo:**

```
def find_even(l):
    return [i for i in l if not i%2]
a_list = [50,23,30,41,99]
print(find_even(a_list))
```

Output:

```
[50, 30]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_even(the_value):
    if the_value % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def find_even(the_list):
    even_list = []
    for sublist in the_list:
        if is_even(sublist):
            even_list.append(sublist)
    return even_list


a_list = [50,23,30,41,99]
print(find_even(a_list))
```

Your indentation for `return even_list` was incorrect resulting in the method terminating and returning the list as soon as it reached the return statement after first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You can write like below

```
def is_even(the_value):
  if the_value % 2 == 0:
      return True
  return False

def find_even(the_list):
  even_list = [item for item in the_list if is_even(item)]
  return even_list


a_list = [50,23,30,41,99,70]
print(find_even(a_list))
```

**Output**

`[50, 30, 70]`

**Explanation**

Your code does not work because your `return even_list` is inside of if condition so when it matches the first even number it appends to the list and return that list, then exit the function.

Comment: Could you explain the error and describe your solution instead of just posting a code snippet

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
def is_even(the_value):
    if the_value % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def find_even(the_list):
    even_list = []
    for sublist in the_list:
        if is_even(sublist):
            even_list.append(sublist)
            # return even_list
    return even_list


a_list = [50,23,30,41,99]
print(find_even(a_list))
```

Output:

```
[50, 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

In def find_even(the_list): you should return even_list out of for loop

```
def find_even(the_list):
    even_list = []
    for sublist in the_list:
        if is_even(sublist):
           even_list.append(sublist)
    return even_list
```